# Why can I load a module in GHCi, while Atom can't find it?

Tags: haskell, atom-editor, haskell-stack

I'm using Haskell with Stack and Atom on Windows 10. Sometimes, I like to just write a stand-alone `.hs` file to play around with various things. When I do that, I prefer to interact with it using GHCi.

Usually, I start it from Git Bash:

```
$ stack ghci --color never
```

From here, I can add modules:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Vector.Unboxed
Prelude Data.Vector.Unboxed>
```

In Atom, however, I'm having trouble with that particular package:

1. Open Atom
2. Create a new `.hs` file
3. Add this following content to it and hit *Save:*

File contents:

```
module Ploeh where

import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
```

When I save the file, I get this error message in Atom:

```
Failed to load interface for `Data.Vector.Unboxed'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

If I remove the import of `Data.Vector.Unboxed`, the error message goes away.

This problem happens specifically with `Data.Vector.Unboxed`. Other modules are either consistently present in both GHCi and Atom, or consistently missing in both environments, but particularly this module behaves inconsistently.

I suppose Atom uses a different engine than the 'global' configuration used by `stack ghci`, but if so, where is it, and can I configure/update it? Why the difference?

---

I'm using the following Atom packages:

- *autocomplete-haskell* 1.0.1
- *haskell-ghc-mod* 2.2.2
- *ide-haskell* 2.2.2
- *ide-haskell-cabal* 2.1.0
- *language-haskell* 1.17.2

Atom itself is version 1.23.2 x64.

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.6.3, Git revision b27e629b8c4ce369e3b8273f04db193b060000db (5454 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.20.0
```

I believe that everything is up-to-date.

I've read https://atom-haskell.github.io/core-packages/haskell-ghc-mod/#using-with-stack and other parts of the documentation to see if I could find some useful information, but I've failed to find something to enlighten me.

Comment: You have to create a cabal file (or yaml file if using hpack) to list down the dependencies. You can quickly get started like this: https://haskell-lang.org/get-started

Comment: @Sibi I've routinely been playing with `.hs` files in Atom for a year or more, and whenever I've stuck to 'basic' modules, I've been doing fine without a `.cabal` or `.yaml` file. I know how to create a 'proper' Stack project and add dependencies. This question is specifically about ad-hoc, exploratory programming.

Comment: Ah, I see. You have them installed as global dependencies. Unfortunately I don't use atom and can't be of much help. As a check you can see if `stack exec ghc-pkg list` has your dependency.

Comment: @Sibi Thank you for looking at the question. I understand that you don't use Atom, so you probably can't help, but I'll leave this response for others to see: `vector-0.12.0.1` is included in the list produced by `stack exec ghc-pkg list`, which seems to be consistent with the fact that `stack ghci` can load the module; it's Atom that can't find it.

Comment: have you found an answer to this problem? I am having this problem even with `Data.Vector`

Comment: @matthias No, I would happily post an answer to my own question if I managed to get it resolved. I've currently abandoned Atom in favour of VS Code for Haskell development, but [that comes with its own set of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48770086/126014).