# How to get Haskero to warn on non-exhaustive pattern matches

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, intero, haskero

I'm currently evaluating [Haskero](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vans.haskero) in *Visual Studio Code* as an alternative Haskell editor instead of *Atom* with [Atom-Haskell](https://atom-haskell.github.io). So far, *Haskero* seems promising, but I miss the compiler warnings I'd usually get from *Atom-Haskell*.

As a way to illustrate the problem, consider this simple repro:

## Steps to reproduce

1. Open *Visual Studio Code* with *Haskero* already installed
2. Add a new Haskell file: `Repro.hs`
3. Add the following content to the file
4. Press *Save*

File contents:

```
module Repro where

foo :: Maybe a -> a
foo (Just x) = x
```

## Expected behaviour

The editor should give a warning to the effect of:

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for `foo': Patterns not matched: Nothing
```

*Atom-Haskell* does this.

## Actual behaviour

Nothing happens. The *Problems* view just states that:

> No problems have been detected in the workspace so far.

## More details

The above steps to reproduce are the simplest ones I could think of, but I see the same (lack of) behaviour when I create a full Stack project and make sure that I've run `stack build intero` in the root of my project directory.

My environment is:

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Stack version 1.6.3, Git revision b27e629b8c4ce369e3b8273f04db193b060000db (5454 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.20.0
- Visual Studio Code version 1.20.0
- Haskero version 1.3.1
- Atom version 1.23.3 x64
- *language-haskell* version 1.17.3

Comment: Are warnings enabled? I just tried running intero, and I had to turn them on editing the cabal file. I guess `stack.yaml` and an `OPTIONS` pragma should work too.

Comment: @chi In one of my 'real' Stack projects, I've tried editing the `.cabal` file like this: `ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -Wall` (I added `-Wall`). This definitely causes `stack build` or `stack test` to display the desired warning, but Haskero doesn't, even after a restart...

Comment: If I recall correctly from when I tried Haskero years ago, you need to install Intero separately. Damned if I can remember the right way to do that though. If you commit an error (rather than a warning) do you get an error from Haskero?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson According to the Haskero documentation, one has to run `stack build intero` in the project folder, which I've also done in my 'actual' projects (I just didn't include this above, as it doesn't seem to be required in order to reproduce the issue). If I write invalid code, Haskero immediately reports this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have to tell Haskero to make any warning into a fatal error (note the `-Werror` flag):

```
"haskero.intero.ghciOptions": [
    "-Wall",
    "-Werror"
]
```

[image]

---

However, I can't really understand why we would have to do this, since this works out of the box:

```
stack ghci --with-ghc intero "--ghci-options=-Wall" --no-build --no-load
```

[image]

That seems to be the way Haskero launches Intero in Visual Studio Code, and in GHCi I can see the warning without passing `-Werror`...

---

Out of curiosity, I've tried the same with hsdev [0.3.1.2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsdev-0.3.1.2), and Sublime Haskell [`91e0d29`](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell/commit/91e0d29a609de091f6adc548be37b1faaf404888), and seems to be working straight out of the box:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would suggest to also keep an eye on https://langserver.org/, and [haskell-ide-engine](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine) in particular, and if that doesn't work out of the box either, I would give [hsdev](https://github.com/mvoidex/hsdev) 0.3.1.2 a shot.

Comment: I can confirm that adding `-Werror` to my options behaves in the way described here. I haven't tried the Sublime Haskell option yet, as I must admit that I'm beginning to experience Haskell tool stack fatigue...

Comment: That's nothing compared to string interpolation in Haskell ;)

Comment: @MarkSeemann Do you still have issue(s) with Haskero or those are fixed in later versions of it? (It looks like you currently [use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52754334/467754) Haskero.)

Comment: Those issues remain. I don't think Haskero has been updated in more than a year, but I also haven't found anything that works better...

Comment: Pretty much same here. Eventually, I realized that the only reliable Haskell 'IDE' can be the command-line. One window edits text. One window displays type errors using `ghcid`. One window tests the Haskell code I write in a REPL. In addition to those, for an IDE-like experience, I would try [haskell-code-explorer](https://github.com/alexwl/haskell-code-explorer), and [debug](https://github.com/ndmitchell/debug) (both are on my list of things to try).